# Error while extracting a zip file

Tags: java

I am trying to unzip a compressed folder using java.util.zip package:

Now my compressed folder structure is :
My compressed folder name is classes.zip
Inside this zip folder i have a classes folder inside that i have sub folders as well as files:
[image]

If you further go inside the www folder then again it has sub folder which is a java package and inside the package structured folder i have .class files.

Now i am trying to unzip this compressed folder and my code is:
package www.eor.com;

```
/**

* A console application that tests the UnzipUtility class
 *
 */
public class UnzipUtilityTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String zipFilePath = "D:/classes.zip";
        String destDirectory = "D:/Dojo";
        UnzipUtility unzipper = new UnzipUtility();
        try {
            unzipper.unzip(zipFilePath, destDirectory);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // some errors occurred
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and the supporting class is :

```
package www.eor.com;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

/**
 * This utility extracts files and directories of a standard zip file to
 * a destination directory.
 */
public class UnzipUtility {
    /**
     * Size of the buffer to read/write data
     */
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
    /**
     * Extracts a zip file specified by the zipFilePath to a directory specified by
     * destDirectory (will be created if does not exists)
     * @param zipFilePath
     * @param destDirectory
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) throws IOException {
        File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
        if (!destDir.exists()) {
            destDir.mkdir();
        }
        ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
        ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        // iterates over entries in the zip file
        while (entry != null) {
            String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                // if the entry is a file, extracts it
                extractFile(zipIn, filePath);
            } else {
                // if the entry is a directory, make the directory
                File dir = new File(filePath);
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            zipIn.closeEntry();
            entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        }
        zipIn.close();
    }
    /**
     * Extracts a zip entry (file entry)
     * @param zipIn
     * @param filePath
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath) throws IOException {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
        }
        bos.close();
    }
}
```

Now when i run **UnzipUtilityTest** class it is giving me exception as :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Dojo\classes\camel-config-xml.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
    at www.cognizant.com.UnzipUtility.extractFile(UnzipUtility.java:59)
    at www.cognizant.com.UnzipUtility.unzip(UnzipUtility.java:41)
    at www.cognizant.com.UnzipUtilityTest.main(UnzipUtilityTest.java:16)
```

Why it is giving this exception and how to rectify this problem?

Comment: The error message obviously tells you that a file cannot be found. Check if the file exists at the given location. Looking at your first screenshot, it looks like the directory is named `D:\classes\classes` instead of `D:\Dojo\classes`.

Comment: try replacing 
ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath))
to
**ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(zipFilePath)));**

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Jesper and HolidayCoder.:) You guys are awesome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably due to the parent of the file   `classes/` does not exists, so it can't create a file in it.

When you extract entries of a zip, you have to create the *parent* folders for the file. A zip does not necessarily contain entries for every single folder. But every entry in zip is of the form `path/to/entry/filename.ext` so you can derive the parent path of the entry and create the parent folders accordingly.

so before extracting the file, do

```
new File(filePath).getParent().mkdirs()
```

Comment: Thanks a lott Gerald.. You a true life saver.. Yes this was the exact problem and your direction solved the problem for me..